# Android - Determining when user increases its speed, and when it decreases

Tags: android, gps, accelerometer

For my Android app I need to determine when the user increases its speed and when it decreases it, I don't need to find the exact speed value, only know if it has increased, decreased or it's the same.
The first solution I came up with was to register a listener for GPS and in the onLocationChanged() method calculate the speed and then check to see if it was greater or equal, but it didn't worked, beacuase the speed was very inaccurate.
Another solution I tried was to use the accelerometer to measure the steps in two seconds, and compare that measure to the previous one, to see what was greater, but I didn't found an exact algorithm. I found some approximation from Android pedometer Github code sample: https://github.com/bagilevi/android-pedometer , but it wasn't too accurate.

So, what solution should I use? What's the most effective way of counting steps with accelerometer?

Thank you.